# Why the origin array of my reducer function are being mutated?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have my variable `sourceArr`, array of objects stored on Window browser scope, and I trying to catch an specific object of this Array making some modifications generating an object through a reducer function, but the problem is when I'm editing the object properties I'm mutating not only my `refined_data` variable but also the corresponding object on my `sourceArr`
What is the reason for this behavior? How can I get my `refined_data` object without mutate my `sourceArr`?

```
var dataSeeker = setInterval(() => {
    if (window.sourceArr) {
        clearInterval(dataSeeker)
        let newArr = sourceArr.filter(data => current_case === data.case_id)
        let refined_data = newArr.reduce((acc, case_data) => {
            case_data.appointment = 'DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss A'
            case_data.name = 'Name'
            return case_data
        }, {})
    }
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source array is being mutated because your reducer function mutates one of its arguments:
case_data.appointment = 'DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss A'
case_data.name = 'Name'
To prevent it from being mutated, don't modify the properties of case_data.
For example, do something like

return { appointment: '...', name: '...' };

Also, a useful reducer function should use the content of both its arguments.